# como puedo retornar este valor en angular

Tags: angular6

esta parte es el componente donde estoy recibiendo un json. este contiene el numero.

```
 public loginA(){

   this.loginService.login(this.usuario).subscribe(
      datos => {return datos['id']}

    );

  }
```

el valor que me muestra ahi datos['id'] puede ser 1 o -1 pero no logro retornarlo a este guard

```
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private loginComponent:LoginComponent){}
  canActivate(){
    if(this.loginComponent.loginA()>0){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }

  }

}
```

aqui da error this.loginComponent.loginA() por que no esta retornando nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las suscripciones a observables no retornan nada, se usan de otra forma. Te muestro un ejemplo a continuación:

Asumiendo que el componente que contiene el método `loginA` se llama "LoginComponent" queda lo siguiente:

```
export class LoginComponent() {
   private id: any;

   constructor() {
   this.loginService.login(this.usuario).subscribe(
      datos => {this.id = datos['id']}
    );
   }

   public loginA(){
      return this.id;
   }
}


export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private loginComponent:LoginComponent){}
  canActivate(){
    if(this.loginComponent.loginA()>0){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }

  }

}
```

espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

El error se puede dar  aquí

`datos['id']`

ya que es un array tienes que acceder al indice del array de esta forma

`datos[indice].propiedad`

Para ti seria algo así

`datos[0].id`

Answer (score 0):

```
public loginA(resId){
    this.loginService.login(this.usuario).subscribe( datos => {
        respId(datos['id']);
    });
}

export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginComponent:LoginComponent){}
      canActivate(){
      this.loginComponent.loginA( idDat => {
        if(idDat > 0){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Serías tan amable por favor de leer [answer], editar tu aporte y explicar como este código soluciona el problema? saludos